# Wrapping an IEnumerable with an ReactiveUI Observable

Tags: reactiveui

Understanding that observables *are not* enumerables, and visa versa:

Using ReactiveUI, what are the recommended ways to wrap an `IEnumerable<T>` with an `IObservable<T>`?

For instance, given the `values` variable below, how could an observable be created that generates an action for each element?

```
var values = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`values.ToObservable()` will create an Observable based on your `IEnumerable`, in which you can then project each item using `Select()`.

Also note that if you need your Observable to then return all your items into an `IObservable<IEnumerable<T>>`, you can buffer the list:

```
values.
   .ToObservable()
   .Select(x => ...)
   .Buffer(values.Count)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: Glad to hear it helped!